# is there an alternative to non-blocking assignment in verilog?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I have written a Verilog code, this code to describe a combinational module. I used a blocking assignment. in other parts, there is must use a nonblocking  assignment. can I use a delay in the blocking assignment to be alternative to a nonblocking assignment... I don't want to mix these two assignments in one module

```
    `timescale 1ns / 1ps

module buffer(datain1,datain2,datain3,datain4,
              s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,
              src_out1,src_out2,src_out3,
                  src_out4,src_out5,src_out6,
                  src_out7,src_out8,src_out9,
                  src_out10,src_out11,src_out12,
                  c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,
              start,clk,load2ads,rb,
                  post_id1,post_id2,post_id3,post_id4,
                  post_r1,post_r2,post_r3,post_r4);

input      [9:0] post_r1,post_r2,post_r3,post_r4;
input      [5:0] post_id1,post_id2,post_id3,post_id4;
input       [2:0] c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12;
input      [87:0] datain1,datain2,datain3,datain4;   // alu result
input       [5:0] s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12;  // task number from ads table
input             start,clk;
output reg [87:0] src_out1,src_out2,src_out3,          // all information from buffer to execution array 
                      src_out4,src_out5,src_out6,         // available sources heading from buff to array
                      src_out7,src_out8,src_out9,
                      src_out10,src_out11,src_out12;
output reg rb;                              
output reg load2ads;                      
reg [9:0]a,b;
reg       [263:0]        // register for temporary save of alu's results
                  t_ads1,t_ads2,t_ads3,
                        t_ads4,t_ads5,t_ads6,
                        t_ads7,t_ads8,t_ads9,
                        t_ads10,t_ads11,t_ads12;

reg [29:0] temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4;
reg [9:0] buff;                                                         
reg       [263:0] buffer [0:63];
reg        [5:0] address_in1,address_in2,address_in3,address_in4; // register for temporary save of alu's addresses

always@(start or datain1 or datain2 or datain3 or datain4 
        or s1 or s2 or s3 or s4 or s5 or s6 or s7 or s8 or s9 or s10 or s11 or s12
          or c1 or c2 or c3 or c4 or c5 or c6 or c7 or c8 or c9 or c10 or c11 or c12)
begin
if(start)
begin

  buffer[0]= 0;
  buffer[1]=264'b000100001011111100000000000100000000000000100001000000000000000000000000000000001000000000010000101111110000000000010000000000000010001100000000000000000000000000000000100000000001000010111111000000000001000000000000001001010000000000000000000000000000000010000000;                     
  buffer[2]=264'b000100001000000100000000001000000000000010100001000000000000000000000000000000000100000000010000100000010000000000100000000001001001001100000000000000000000000000000000010000000001000010000001000000000010000000000100010101010000000000000000000000000000000001000000;
  buffer[3]=264'b000100001000001000000000001100000000000000100001000000000000000000000000000000000100000000010000100000100000000000110000000000000010001100000000000000000000000000000000010000000001000010000010000000000011000000000000001001010000000000000000000000000000000001000000;
  buffer[4]=264'b000100001000001100000000010000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000001000000000010000100000110000000001000000000000000000001100000000000000000000000000000000100000000001000010000011000000000100000000000000000001010000000000000000000000000000000010000000;
  buffer[63]=264'b00000000000000000000011111100000000110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;


end
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
rb=0;

/*address_in1=datain1[65:60];
address_in2=datain2[65:60];
address_in3=datain3[65:60];
address_in4=datain4[65:60];
*/

buffer [datain1[65:60]][263:176]=datain1;
buffer [datain2[65:60]][263:176]=datain2;
buffer [datain3[65:60]][263:176]=datain3;
buffer [datain4[65:60]][263:176]=datain4;

// insert alu result into buffer and shift the data into the next ctr 

if(s1 !=0)
begin
      t_ads1 =buffer[s1];

     if(c1==0) begin src_out1=t_ads1[263:176];src_out1[43:41]=0; end
else if(c1==1) begin src_out1=t_ads1[175:88]; src_out1[43:41]=1; end
else if(c1==2) begin src_out1=t_ads1[87:0];   src_out1[43:41]=2; end
else src_out1=0;
end   
else src_out1=0;



if(s2 !=0)
begin
      t_ads2 =buffer[s2];

      if(c2==0) begin src_out2=t_ads2[263:176];src_out2[43:41]=0;end 
else  if(c2==1) begin src_out2=t_ads2[175:88]; src_out2[43:41]=1;end
else if(c2==2)  begin src_out2=t_ads2[87:0];   src_out2[43:41]=2;end
else src_out2=0;
 end 
else src_out2=0;


if(s3 !=0)
begin

      t_ads3 =buffer[s3];

      if(c3==0) begin src_out3=t_ads3[263:176];src_out3[43:41]=0; end
else  if(c3==1) begin src_out3=t_ads3[175:88];src_out3[43:41]=1; end
else  if(c3==2) begin src_out3=t_ads3[87:0];src_out3[43:41]=2; end
else src_out3=0;
end  
else src_out3=0;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if(s4 !=0)
begin

  t_ads4 =buffer[s4];

      if(c4==0)  begin src_out4=t_ads4[263:176]; src_out4[43:41]=0; end                                                                                                                        

else  if(c4==1)  begin src_out4=t_ads4[175:88]; src_out4[43:41]=1; end                                                                                                                                                               

else  if(c4==2) begin src_out4=t_ads4[87:0];src_out4[43:41]=2; end 
else src_out4=0;
 end
else src_out4=0;


if(s5 !=0)
begin
      t_ads5 =buffer[s5];

      if(c5==0)  begin src_out5=t_ads5[263:176]; src_out5[43:41]=0; end                                                                                                                        
else  if(c5==1)  begin src_out5=t_ads5[175:88]; src_out5[43:41]=1; end                                                                                                                                                          
else  if(c5==2)  begin src_out5=t_ads5[87:0]; src_out5[43:41]=2; end 
else src_out5=0;
end
else src_out5=0;


if(s6 !=0)
begin
      t_ads6 =buffer[s6];

      if(c6==0) begin src_out6=t_ads6[263:176]; src_out6[43:41]=0; end                                                                                                                       
else  if(c6==1) begin src_out6=t_ads6[175:88];  src_out6[43:41]=1; end                                                                                                                                                                
else  if(c6==2) begin src_out6=t_ads6[87:0]; src_out6[43:41]=2; end
else src_out6=0;
end
else src_out6=0;



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if(s7 !=0)
begin

t_ads7 =buffer[s7];

     if(c7==0) begin src_out7=t_ads7[263:176]; src_out7[43:41]=0; end

else if(c7==1) begin src_out7=t_ads7[175:88]; src_out7[43:41]=1; end

else if(c7==2) begin src_out7=t_ads7[87:0]; src_out7[43:41]=2; end
else src_out7=0;
end

else src_out7=0;


if(s8 !=0)
begin

t_ads8 =buffer[s8];

     if(c8==0) begin src_out8=t_ads8[263:176]; src_out8[43:41]=0; end

else if(c8==1) begin src_out8=t_ads8[175:88]; src_out8[43:41]=1; end

else  if(c8==2)begin src_out8=t_ads8[87:0];src_out8[43:41]=2; end
else src_out8=0;
 end
else src_out8=0;



if(s9 !=0)
begin

t_ads9 =buffer[s9];

     if(c9==0)begin src_out9=t_ads9[263:176]; src_out9[43:41]=0; end

else if(c9==1)begin  src_out9=t_ads9[175:88]; src_out9[43:41]=1; end

else  if(c9==2)begin src_out9=t_ads9[87:0]; src_out9[43:41]=2; end
else src_out9=0;
end
else src_out9=0;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if(s10 !=0)
begin

t_ads10 =buffer[s10];

     if(c10==0)begin  src_out10=t_ads10[263:176]; src_out10[43:41]=0; end

else if(c10==1)begin src_out10=t_ads10[175:88];src_out10[43:41]=1; end

else  if(c10==2)begin src_out10=t_ads10[87:0];src_out10[43:41]=2; end
else src_out10=0;
end
else src_out10=0;


if(s11 !=0)
begin

t_ads11 =buffer[s11];

     if(c11==0)begin src_out11=t_ads11[263:176];src_out11[43:41]=0; end

else if(c11==1)begin src_out11=t_ads11[175:88];src_out11[43:41]=1; end

else  if(c11==2)begin src_out11=t_ads11[87:0];src_out11[43:41]=2; end
else src_out11=0;
end
else src_out11=0;


if(s12 !=0)
begin

t_ads12 =buffer[s12];

     if(c12==0)begin src_out12=t_ads12[263:176];src_out12[43:41]=0; end

else if(c12==1)begin src_out12=t_ads12[175:88];src_out12[43:41]=1; end

else  if(c12==2)begin src_out12=t_ads12[87:0];src_out12[43:41]=2; end
else src_out12=0;
end
else src_out12=0;
```

this part I want to use an equivalent alternative way

```
if((datain1[49]==1)||(datain2[49]==1)||(datain3[49]==1)||(datain4[49]==1)) 
begin
buffer[1][59:50]  <=buffer[1][147:138];
buffer[1][147:138]<=buffer[1][235:226];

buffer[2][59:50]  <=buffer[2][147:138];
buffer[2][147:138]<=buffer[2][235:226];

buffer[3][59:50]  <=buffer[3][147:138];
buffer[3][147:138]<=buffer[3][235:226];

buffer[4][59:50]  <=buffer[4][147:138];
buffer[4][147:138]<=buffer[4][235:226];

buffer[5][59:50]  <=buffer[5][147:138];
buffer[5][147:138]<=buffer[5][235:226];

buffer[6][59:50]  <=buffer[6][147:138];
buffer[6][147:138]<=buffer[6][235:226];

buffer[7][59:50]  <=buffer[7][147:138];
buffer[7][147:138]<=buffer[7][235:226];

buffer[8][59:50]  <=buffer[8][147:138];
buffer[8][147:138]<=buffer[8][235:226];

buffer[9][59:50]  <=buffer[9][147:138];
buffer[9][147:138]<=buffer[9][235:226];

buffer[10][59:50]  <=buffer[10][147:138];
buffer[10][147:138]<=buffer[10][235:226];

buffer[11][59:50]  <=buffer[11][147:138];
buffer[11][147:138]<=buffer[11][235:226];

buffer[12][59:50]  <=buffer[12][147:138];
buffer[12][147:138]<=buffer[12][235:226];

buffer[13][59:50]  <=buffer[13][147:138];
buffer[13][147:138]<=buffer[13][235:226];

buffer[14][59:50]  <=buffer[14][147:138];
buffer[14][147:138]<=buffer[14][235:226];

buffer[15][59:50]  <=buffer[15][147:138];
buffer[15][147:138]<=buffer[15][235:226];

buffer[16][59:50]  <=buffer[16][147:138];
buffer[16][147:138]<=buffer[16][235:226];

buffer[17][59:50]  <=buffer[17][147:138];
buffer[17][147:138]<=buffer[17][235:226];

buffer[18][59:50]  <=buffer[18][147:138];
buffer[18][147:138]<=buffer[18][235:226];

buffer[19][59:50]  <=buffer[19][147:138];
buffer[19][147:138]<=buffer[19][235:226];

buffer[20][59:50]  <=buffer[20][147:138];
buffer[20][147:138]<=buffer[20][235:226];

buffer[21][59:50]  <=buffer[21][147:138];
buffer[21][147:138]<=buffer[21][235:226];

buffer[22][59:50]  <=buffer[22][147:138];
buffer[22][147:138]<=buffer[22][235:226];

buffer[23][59:50]  <=buffer[23][147:138];
buffer[23][147:138]<=buffer[23][235:226];

buffer[24][59:50]  <=buffer[24][147:138];
buffer[24][147:138]<=buffer[24][235:226];

buffer[25][59:50]  <=buffer[25][147:138];
buffer[25][147:138]<=buffer[25][235:226];

buffer[26][59:50]  <=buffer[26][147:138];
buffer[26][147:138]<=buffer[26][235:226];
rb=1;

end

end


endmodule
```

Comment: what can i use to get the same result as nba?

Comment: You have no delay! They all be executed at the same time! Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Slightly off topic, but is there a reason you are using the 1995 coding style? If you used 2001 coding style you can simplify `always@(start or datain1 or datain2 or datain3 or datain4 or s1 or s2 or s3 or s4 or s5 or s6 or s7 or s8 or s9 or s10 or s11 or s12 or c1 or c2 or c3 or c4 or c5 or c6 or c7 or c8 or c9 or c10 or c11 or c12)` to `always @*` (auto-sensitivity list)

Comment: There are some inputs I don't need them in the sensitivity list @Greg

Comment: The typical synthesis tool will ignore the sensitivity list of combinational logic. When you intentionally omit signals from sensitivity, you are at risk of of a behavioral mismatch between RTL and gates.

Answer (score 1):

> You should not use Nonblocking Assignments in Combinational logic
>   ideally.

**Hence in your design, there are serious issues regarding timings.**

However, if you make your design synchronous, then you can avoid the usage of NBA with the use of `Clocking Block` in Systemverilog.

```
clocking cb @(posedge clk)
  input a, b, c;
  // Other Signals as per your requirement
endclocking
```

Now the inputs declared in the clocking block by default have `#1step` delay, which means that they will hold the value of preponed region of current timeslot or postponed region of previous timeslot (which both are equal).

Hence you can use those signals anywhere in your design and you can eliminate the usage of NBA.

> **However, one thing to note is that Clocking Blocks are not synthesizable.**

Here is one working example :

```
module temp();
  reg a, b, c;
  reg clock;

  initial
  begin
    $monitor("@%0t: a - %b, b - %b, c - %b", $time(), a, b, c);
    clock = 1;
    a = 1;
    b = 0;
    c = 1;
    #100 $finish();
  end

  always #5 clock = ~clock;

  clocking cb @(negedge clock);
    input a, b, c;
  endclocking

  always @(posedge clock)
  begin
    a = cb.c;
    b = cb.a;
    c = cb.b;
  end
endmodule
```

***Please note that if you keep both clocking event and always block event same (like both posedge/negedge), then there can be a potential race condition between them and the value sampled as input from clocking block may be inaccurate.***

Comment: Its the first time i will use the clocking ... how can i use it with my example?

Comment: You will need to first convert your example in clock dependent sequential logic, then I can guide you.