# how to use Clocking block in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

How can i use the clocking block in verilog to get an equivalent code to the nonblocking assignment

```
if((datain1[49]==1)||(datain2[49]==1)||(datain3[49]==1)||(datain4[49]==1)) 
begin
buffer[1][59:50]  <=buffer[1][147:138];
buffer[1][147:138]<=buffer[1][235:226];

buffer[2][59:50]  <=buffer[2][147:138];
buffer[2][147:138]<=buffer[2][235:226];

buffer[3][59:50]  <=buffer[3][147:138];
buffer[3][147:138]<=buffer[3][235:226];

buffer[4][59:50]  <=buffer[4][147:138];
buffer[4][147:138]<=buffer[4][235:226];
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Clocking blocks are not going to help you with what you are trying to achieve.

Your [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42391563/1959732) has `buffer` assigning back itself (asynchronous feedback). It doesn't matter that `buffer` is not part of the sensitivity list, synthesizers will treat it as if it is part of the sensitivity list. You have a clock input, you should use it.

I suggest you change your coding style to a two-always block approach. One always block should be pure conbinational logic for next-state calculations.  The second always block is for synchronous assignments. If you want to learn more about different coding styles and their strengths and weaknesses, I suggest [this paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsICU2002_FSMFundamentals.pdf) by Cliff Cummings.

You code should be something like this:

```
// Use 'reg' for Verilog; 'logic' is recommended for SytemVerilog
reg       [263:0] buffer [0:63]; // flopped value
reg       [263:0] next_buffer [0:63]; // next-state of buffer

// Use whatever name you want for the indexes so long as they are unique per always block
integer comb_idx; ff_idx; 

// always_comb // <<== SystemVerilog
always @* // <<== Verilog (IEEE1364-2001)
begin
  for(comb_idx = 0; comb_idx<64; comb_idx=comb_idx+1) begin
    next_buffer[comb_idx] = buffer[comb_idx]; // initialize
  end

  if(start) begin
    next_buffer[0] = 0;
    // ...
  end

  // ... other conbinational and next-state calculations ...

  if((datain1[49]==1)||(datain2[49]==1)||(datain3[49]==1)||(datain4[49]==1)) 
  begin
    // we can use a loop for this
    for(comb_idx = 1; comb_idx<27; comb_idx=comb_idx+1) begin
      next_buffer[comb_idx][59:50]   = buffer[comb_idx][147:138];
      next_buffer[comb_idx][147:138] = buffer[comb_idx][235:226];
    end
  end
end

/*
// SystemVerilog
always_ff @(posedge clk)
begin
  // ... other synchronous assignments ...

  // SystemVerilog can assign unpacked arrays of same dimensions on one shot
  buffer <= next_buffer; type
end
*/

// Verilog
always @(posedge clk)
begin
  // ... other synchronous assignments ...
  for(ff_idx = 0; ff_idx<64; ff_idx=ff_idx+1) begin
    // Verilog cannot assign unpacked arrays in one shot
    buffer[ff_idx] <= next_buffer[ff_idx];
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a clocking block to get an equivalent to a non-blocking assignment.

System-Verilog has 9 *scheduling regions*:

```
from prev time step
        |
     PREPONED
        |
      ACTIVE
        |
     INACTIVE
        |
       NBA
        |
     OBSERVED
        |
    RE-ACTIVE
        |
   RE-INACTIVE
        |
      RE-NBA
        |
    POSTPONED
        |
        V
 to next time step
```

Signals driven by a clocking block are driven in the RE-NBA region whereas variables are assigned to using a non-blocking assignment in the NBA region.

Comment: how can i replace a NBA with any type to keep the same result... NBA cause a problem in my code because there are mix of blocking and NBA in the same module

Comment: Clocking blocks are only for your testbench. Are you talking about your testbench code or your design?

Comment: You can't use clocking blocks in your design. They are not synthesisable. They are for your testbench only. You should not have scheduling difficulties mixing blocking and non-block assignments as long as you do it right. Basically, combinational logic should use blocking assignments and sequential logic should use non-blocking assignments. See [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260145/having-trouble-with-always-block-in-verilog/41263924#41263924).

Comment: when i do this in the combinational logic 
 `buffer[1][59:50] =buffer[1][147:138];
buffer[1][147:138]=buffer[1][235:226];`
it dosen't work right, but by using NBA it gives the correct answer
what can i do?

Comment: Is this code really combinational? What hardware are you expecting `buffer` to infer (to become)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391563/is-there-an-alternative-to-non-blocking-assignment-in-verilog this my code

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about Systemverilog or Verilog? There is NO clocking block in Verilog.